# Windows service - unrecoverable FtpWebRequest timeout when an FTP provider maintenance window occurs

Tags: c#, ftp, timeout

I have a windows service, where every hour on a scheduled basis it downloads an FTP file from an FTP server. It uses the following code to do this:

```
var _request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(configuration.Url);
_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
_request.Timeout = 20000;
_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("auser", "apassword");

using (var _response = (FtpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
using (var _responseStream = _response.GetResponseStream())
using (var _streamReader = new StreamReader(_responseStream))
{
    this.c_fileData = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Normally, the downloading the FTP data works perfectly fine, however every few months the FTP server provider notifies us that some maintenance needs to be performed. So once maintenance is started (usually only 2 or 3 hours), our hourly attempt of a FTP download fails - i.e. it timeout, which is expected.

The problem is that post the maintenance window our windows service continues to timeout every time it attempts to download the file. Our windows service also has retry logic, but each retry also times out.

Once we do a restart of the windows service, the application starts downloading FTP files successfully again.

Does anyone know why we have to restart the windows service in order to recover from this failure?, Could it be a network issue e.g. DNS?

**Note 1:** There are similar questions to this one already, but they do not involve a maintenance window and they also do not have any credible answers either

**Note 2:** We profiled the memory of the application and it seems all ftp objects are being disposed of correctly.

**Note 3:** We executed a console app with same FTP code post maintenance window and it works fine, while the windows service was still timing out

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You said that the console app with same FTP code doesn't fail. Have you already considered that the deadlock might be outside this code? Who call this code and how?

Comment: We have considered this, but we are certain based on stack trace information that the FTP code is where the error resides

Comment: Can you post the stack trace information?

Answer (score 2):

We eventually got to the bottom of this issue albeit not all questions were answered.

We found that when we used a different memory profiler, it showed up that two FtpWebRequest objects were in memory and had not been disposed for days in the process. These objects were what was causing the problem i.e. they were not being properly disposed.

From research, to solve the issue, we did the following:

1. Set the keep-alive to false
2. Set the connections lease timeout to a limited timeout value
3. Set the max idle time to a limited timeout value
4. Wrapped in a try/catch/finally, where the request is aborted in the finally block

We changed the code to the following:

```
var _request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(configuration.Url);
_request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
_request.Timeout = 20000;
_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("auser", "apassword");
_request.KeepAlive = false;
_request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 20000;
_request.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 20000;

try
{
    using (var _response = (FtpWebResponse)_request.GetResponse())
    using (var _responseStream = _response.GetResponseStream())
    using (var _streamReader = new StreamReader(_responseStream))
    {
        this.c_fileData = _streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
catch (Exception genericException)
{
    throw genericException;
}
finally
{
    _request.Abort();
}
```

To be honest we are not sure if we needed to do everything here but the problem no longer exists i.e. objects do not hang around, the application still functions post a maintenance window so we are happy!